# Cycling through elements periodically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've found plenty of examples to show/hide divs with a timeout in JavaScript, but I can't seem to solve my exact issue here.

I have six divs. I want to cycle through from 1 to 6 and then all over again, every 10 seconds. My current code is working as far as hiding the original div (always want div #one to show first on page load) after 10 seconds and showing the next one in sequence.

How can I cleanly cycle through these in order every 10 seconds?

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
      startCycle();
    });

    function startCycle(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('three').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('four').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('five').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('six').style.display = 'none';
        }, 10000); // 10000ms = 10s
    }
```

```css
    #one{
        display: block;
    }

    #two,
    #three,
    #four,
    #five,
    #six{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">Test One</div>
<div id="two">Test Two</div>
<div id="three">Test Three</div>
<div id="four">Test Four</div>
<div id="five">Test Five</div>
<div id="six">Test Six</div>
```

Comment: if you use numbers in the id you can use a for loop instead of selecting them each time.... e.g .getElementById(\`test-${i}\`) and the id would be "test-1", would certainly make things clearer. Also why are 2-5 not have any display set? are they display block or display none?  I would use a while loop with an increment value and for each loop increment it by one and when it gets to the end reset to 0 or 1... or something along those lines...

Comment: Sounds like you're basically asking for a slideshow. Have you searched that topic? It's well-trodden ground.

Comment: @tukars that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Hint: don't rely on IDs. Use index.

Comment: @isherwood I didn't think about it since there are no images but it totally makes sense that I should search that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you put those `div` elements in a container element, so you don't actually need the `id` attributes anymore.

Then, as you use jQuery, use `hide` and `show` calls. You can use the remainder operator (`%`) to "cycle" an index variable.

For the sake of quickly checking this solution, I reduced the delay to half a second:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
    startCycle($("#container").children(), 0);
});

function startCycle($elems, i) {
    $elems.hide().eq(i % $elems.length).show();
    setTimeout(() => startCycle($elems, i + 1), 500); // 500ms = 0.5s
}
```

```css
#container > div { display: none }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <div>Test One</div>
    <div>Test Two</div>
    <div>Test Three</div>
    <div>Test Four</div>
    <div>Test Five</div>
    <div>Test Six</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
      const eList = document.getElementsByClassName('hideMe');

      Object.keys(eList).forEach((elem, index) => {
        setTimeout(function(){
          toogle(eList[index])
        }, 10000 * index);
      });
   });

    function toogle(elem) {
      if (elem) elem.classList.toggle('hide')
    }
```

```css
.hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="one" class='hideMe hide'>Test One</div>
<div id="two" class='hideMe hide'>Test Two</div>
<div id="three" class='hideMe hide'>Test Three</div>
<div id="four" class='hideMe hide'>Test Four</div>
<div id="five" class='hideMe hide'>Test Five</div>
<div id="six" class='hideMe hide'>Test Six</div>
```

Comment: don't know. ur solution is, by far, better